# How to send a post request with data using python requests module?

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I want to take the password from the user and then send a post request to a url (`'http://example.com/welcome?user='` + (some user name)). So how can I send a post request with data?

Comment: That's a query string in the URL, which is usually just a GET request, not a POST..

Comment: What part of the [`requests` documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#make-a-request) isn't clear on this? What have you tried, and what problems did you encounter?

Comment: Have you even skimmed [the docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/)? This is explained in the QuickStart section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = {'password': SOME_PASSWORD}
requests.post(url, data=data)
```

your url would be something like

```
'http://example.com/welcome?user={}'.format(username)'
```

Then at you server you have the username in the get parameters and password in the post parameters.  But the you could just put the user and the password in the data dictionary and post both fields

EDIT:

I do agree with Martijn that passing some data in get and some in post is a bad idea, so if there is not a good reason to do it you probably should avoid it.

I also like the idea of using the requests params argument and data arguments if you absolutely need to pass them the username in GET and the password in POST, so your request would become:

```
requests.post('http://example.com/welcome', data={'password': SOME_PASSWORD}, params={'user': SOME_USERNAME})
```

but the best way is:

```
requests.post('http://example.com/welcome', data={'password': SOME_PASSWORD, 'user': SOME_USERNAME})
```

Apologies for the short answer previously, it was a quick one in a coffee break. Please forgive me :-)

Comment: This uses a POST body, not the query string in the URL itself. It is *not clear* what the OP wants here.

Comment: Moreover, if it was this simple, then this is surely a duplicate question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: If the OP wants to pass the username in the query and something else (like a password) in the POST data, that may be a stupid thing to do, but this answer is the way to do it… Still, it might be a better answer if it explained that it was a stupid thing to do, and why.

Comment: I would **not** use formatting to build the URL. You can use the same technique for URL parameters too; use `params=data` instead of (or *in addition* to) using the `data` parameter.

Comment: @abarnert: exactly; if you are going to answer this early, then be more complete, try to address the various possibilities that the question leaves wide open (not understanding the difference between GET and POST, not being clear as to how the information needs to be passed in, the possibility to use either `data` or `params` or both, the possibility that the server needs to get the data as JSON or other encoding deviating from the standard `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` even).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Agreed. I'm not saying the question is answerable as asked, just that this could be an answer to a question that isn't a dup and might conceivably be what the OP wanted to ask. If I'd answered it, I would have written 3 pages that the OP would never read, of course. :)